# Help me find the ISSN number of the journal or book and its publisher URL

Tags: journals, publishers, library, digital-libraries

I have been trying locate an article/Journal from one of the citations. I am in need of the article to complete my literature search for project. Help me locate ISSN number of the book or Journal and its online URL cited as below attached is the resource from where took the citation .

*"Anatkov A, Gekova K. The use of large intravenous doses of iron in the treatment of iron deficiency anaemia. Problems of Haematology and Blood Transfusions in Medicine andPhysioculture 1970; 295-8[image]."*

Comment: That's the sort of work your university librarians are actually very good at!

Comment: I think it's Russian, Problemy Gematologii i Perelivaniya Krovi. Looks like it morphed into Gematologiia i Transfuziologiia. See https://www.safetylit.org/week/journalpage.php?jid=11123